# C# Signed Requests -> Trying to convert the PHP sample on fb to C#, or is there a better way?

Tags: php, request, facebook-c#-sdk, signed

how are you?
I'm trying to convert the PHP sample on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ to C# but I have trouble with $_REQUEST['signed_request']. I'm not sure how to convert that. I was thinking Request.Form["signed_request"]; but I always get a null value. What is the equivalent? Or better yet, is there another/better way of going through a signed request? What I'm looking to do is get the page id of the page that the application is running from (basically from a custom tab).

Thank you very much!

-TS...

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You retrieve query string parameters using the `Request` array:

```
Request["myvar"];
```

Note: that is for GET and POST variables.

Answer (score 0):

if using FB C# SDK.

var signedRequest = FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest;